# Unstandardized beta with an E in it

Tags: notation, arithmetic

I have an unstandardized beta of -2.615-E5. What does the E mean? I have never seen this. Thanks!

Comment: Usually $-2.615 \times 10^{5}$. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation (P.S. Did you copy this exactly? Are you sure it wasn't -2.615E-5 instead?)

Comment: Thank you! It was E-5 and I read the article. That helped.

Answer (score 2):

@Nick Cox is right, consider these examples:
\begin{align}
2&.615\text{E}5 &=~~~ 2&.615\times10^5 &= &~~~261,500  \\
2&.615\text{E}-5 &=~~~ 2&.615\times10^{-5} &= &~~~0.00002615  \\
-2&.615\text{E}-5 &= -2&.615\times10^{-5} &= &-0.00002615  \\
-2&.615\text{E}5 &= -2&.615\times10^5 &= &-261,500  
\end{align}

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right! It was E-5.

Comment: No problem, @JanBrewington.

Comment: Thank you. I am using the standardized in my report, which is -0 as above. I will look at the wikepedia article to define the E. Thank you!