# Factor analysis using spss

Tags: spss, factor-analysis

I got determinant value– 5.84E-007. What does it mean? Should I continue the work or not? What do I have to do?

And also I obtain the following Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin value and Bartlett's Test results

```
Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin Measure of Sampling Adequacy.       .793
Bartlett's Test of Sphericity   Approx. Chi-Square  3.452E3
                                                df      253
                                              Sig.     .000
```

Bartlett's Test of Sphericity   Approx. Chi-Square  3.452E3 - is this value is correct?

Comment: I doubt anyone could answer these questions without a lot more detail. I know I can't.

Comment: This could partly be that E notation is unfamiliar to the poster. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64877/unstandardized-beta-with-an-e-in-it for that story. But in general it is futile to ask whether results from a longstanding program are correct unless you (a) have specific grounds for suspecting a mistake and (b) also tell us what your data are so that we can check with other software or otherwise assess your claim.

Comment: This question doesn't seem so bad to me. A value that tiny for the determinant strikes me as suspect to to a *very near* ill-conditioned  correlation matrix as the input for `FACTOR`. So you might reorient the question to something along the lines `The determinant of my correlation matrix is *really* tiny - should I be worried about the results of factor analysis?`. That seems to me to be on topic here. Posting your correlation matrix would help others with there assessment.

Comment: Only in regards to Bartlett's test of Sphericity does the poster appear the poster is asking whether the results from SPSS are correct... however the more probable question being asked is whether that result is concordant with the other results.  It looks like their primary question is how to proceed when the determinant is very small.

Comment: please give your valuable suggestion.how to proceed when the determinant is very small. the value of determinant i got (5.84E-007)